# Misc Issues Upgrading from SP 2010 to SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010

We are deploying an upgrade from SP2010 to SP Online.  A few things are not as desired after the migration and are really cosmetic in nature.

1. On the team/project landing page, some web-parts (lists usually) auto-stretch to fill the width of the column.  Some do not.  The desired look is to auto-stretch.  I cant seem to find how to do this.  Moreover, if I delete the web-part and re-add it, I lose the auto-stretch that was there.
2. The look of the new web parts leave a lot to be desired.  Most notably, the "+ New Item or edit this list" is the most visually dominant element on the page, more pronounced than the title of the web-part.  In SP2010, the "add new item" icon was small and below to list/library.  Can I enforce the look of the SP2010 style? Or perhaps just get rid of the "+ New Item or edit this list"

Thanks in advance for the advice